# PHP saving a string to a file "as is" including eg \n

Tags: php, file-io, special-characters

I have a variable which contains a string, I don't know what the string might be but it could contain special characters.

I'd like to output that into a text file "as is".
So if there is for example a string "my string\n" I want the text file to show exactly that and not interpret the \n as a line feed / new line.

Comment: Then make sure it's "as is" in the string, e.g. `"my string \\n"` or `'my string \n'`. PHP is not doing any transformation on the *actual* data.

Comment: If you have a string with a newline and write it to a file the newline will be there.  Have you tried it?  You may not see it rendered as a newline in notepad or similar and you won't see it rendered in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for "\n" is to replace any potential new line character with the literal characters.
`str_replace("\n", '\n', $myString)`

Not sure what the general case may be though for other potential special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Then make sure it's "as is" in the string, e.g. `"my string \\n"` or `'my string \n'`. PHP is not doing any transformation on the *actual* data - the transformation of `"\n"` to a newline happens *when* PHP parses the [string literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in code.

Now, assuming that you want an *actual newline character* (`"\n"`) in the data/string to be written as a sequence of *two characters* (`'\n'`), then it must be converted back, e.g.:

```
# \n is converted to a NL due to double-quoted literal ..
$strWithNl = "hello\n world";
# but given arbitrary data, we change it back ..
$strWithSlashN = str_replace("\n", '\n', $strWithNl);
```

There are likely better (read: existing) functions to "de-escape" a string [per a given set of rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), but the above should hopefully show the concepts.

---

While everything above is true/valid (or should be corrected if not), I had a little extra time on my hands to create an `escape_as_double_quoted_literal` function.

Given an "ASCII encoded" string `$str` and `$escaped = escape_as_double_quoted_literal($str)`, it should be the case that `eval("\"$escaped\"") == $str`. I'm not exactly sure when this particular function will be useful (and please don't say for eval!), but since I did not find such a function after some immediate searches, this is [my quick implementation](http://ideone.com/li8RvV) of such. *YMMV*.

```
function escape_as_double_quoted_literal_matcher ($m) {
    $ch = $m[0];
    switch ($ch) {
        case "\n": return '\n';
        case "\r": return '\r';
        case "\t": return '\t';
        case "\v": return '\v';
        case "\e": return '\e';
        case "\f": return '\f';
        case "\\": return '\\\\';
        case "\$": return '\$';
        case "\"": return '\\"';
        case "\0": return '\0';
        default:
            $h = dechex(ord($ch));
            return '\x' . (strlen($h) > 1 ? $h : '0' . $h);
    }
}

function escape_as_double_quoted_literal ($val) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
            "|[^\x20\x21\x23\x25-\x5b\x5e-\x7e]|",
            "escape_as_double_quoted_literal_matcher",
            $val);
}
```

And the usage of such:

```
$text = "\0\1\xff\"hello\\world\"\n\$";
echo escape_as_double_quoted_literal($text);
```

(Note that `'\1'` is encoded as `\x01`; both are equivalent in a PHP double-quoted string literal.)

Comment: As I say, I don't know what the variable might be so your first paragraph doesn't apply. And your second, there is no assuming, it is stated in what I asked and the example given.  I'd be interested in the most useful (read: correct) way to do it in the general case.

Comment: @iss42 The most correct for doing such a conversion will depend upon the *actual rules* desired - do you wish to "convert the string into the most compact PHP string literal form?" Other? (Handling Unicode is an entirely different ballgame.)

Comment: The first paragraph is correct. Have you tried it and found a specific problem? PHP will NOT transform the string `"\n"` to a newline unless it is a string literal in the source code.

Comment: @mcrumley First paragraph is NOT correct, I don't KNOW what the string contains - simple.

Comment: @iss42 Not knowing what the string contains does not make the information in this response false. The idea of "as is" that is being presented by the question is *vague* and further attempts to solicit details (see my previous comment) have result in no response.

Comment: @user2864740 yes it does. I cannot possible make sure it's as is in the string at that point.